# Application hidden queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g

While trying to troubleshoot a couple of bad queries, the application got upgraded. I opened an S.R with the vendor to see what new queries are running but I could not see anything new running in the database. The person I dealt with from support said that they hide their code. We have the usual solution stack: APPLICATION <--> MIDLLEWARE <--> DATABASE.
Is there a way to get around this?
Thanks in advance.